# Blade view doesn't reflects the changes

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working on a laravel project and created some view but when I try to change the views it doesn't reflects any changes i made there.
i am using Ubuntu as OS and my PHP version is 7.4

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWkyB.jpg

I also tried

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

then i refresh the page and get the same old complied data on my view.

Comment: Did you try deleting your browser cache?

Comment: Welcome to SO. People won't click of a foreign URL which has all the powers to be evil: do not do that. You should rather show your PHP code.

Comment: @AndreaGolin yes i even used incognito mode

Comment: formatting improvment

Comment: If you are using op-cache plugin from php disable it, i had some problems with op-cache on development environment

Comment: Also, please don't post images - this is SO, for coding, not imgur. Post the relevant parts of your code as text.

Comment: @Christian Opcode Caching is disabled